# How to sum a dynamic range with a moving 'total' cell?

Tags: excel, vba

In the screenshot below, I would like to sum the dynamic range in column Y (and Z). The *SUM* formula is currently in cell Y8.

I will not know how many items will be added after items A and B. This list will grow as users input more data.

Is there a way to sum Y6:Y# as the **SUBTOTAL COST** cell moves down when new rows are added? 
Would a recorded macro help solve this?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: [Here is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end) what should help, and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) should help to get one row down. But the solution much depends on how your data rows will appear on the sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX:

```
=SUM(INDEX(Y:Y,6):INDEX(Y:Y,ROW()-1))
```

Now no matter where the rows are added it will sum from row 6 to the row just above where the formula is placed.

Comment: Thank you for the quick fix!